# Finding maximum value in a loop

Tags: python, loops, if-statement

This is just an introductory class code, and i'm wondering how to find the max of all the next_value variable and compare it to the first_value to print the maximum. My if statement is close but I'm not sure how to fix it

```
maximum = 0.0
value = int(input("Enter the number of values to process: "))

first_value = float(input("First value: "))
next_value_total = 0


for i in range(1, value):
    next_value = float(input("Next value: "))
    next_value_total += next_value
    if first_value <= next_value:
        maximum = next_value
    elif first_value > next_value:
        maximum = first_value

total = next_value_total + first_value
print("The total is {:.1f}".format(total))
print("The maximum is {:.1f}".format(maximum))
```

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: It isn't always printing the maximum correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to keep my answer as clean and simple as possible:

```
value = int(input("Enter the number of values to process: "))

first_value = float(input("First value: "))

total = first_value
maximum = first_value

for i in range(1, value):
    next_value = float(input("Next value: "))
    total += next_value
    if maximum <= next_value:
        maximum = next_value

print("The total is {:.1f}".format(total))
print("The maximum is {:.1f}".format(maximum))
```

Comment: Thank you, I just added another if statement to compare it to the first_value to find the true maximum and I think it works

Comment: If I enter the numbers you suggested: number of values to process: 5, First value: 100, Next value: 90, Next value: 105, Next value: 80, Next value: 102, my code prints: The total is 477.0, The maximum is 105.0 (which is correct)

Answer (score 1):

I would just put the values in a list and get the sum and max later, like so:

```
value = int(input("Enter the number of values to process: "))
values = []

for i in range(value):
    next_value = float(input("Next value: "))
    values.append(next_value)

print("The total is {:.1f}".format(sum(values)))
print("The maximum is {:.1f}".format(max(values)))
```

However, if you want to keep the same structure:

```
maximum = 0.0
value = int(input("Enter the number of values to process: "))

first_value = float(input("First value: "))
next_value_total = 0
maximum = first_value  # Note: initialize the maximum here

for i in range(1, value):
    next_value = float(input("Next value: "))
    next_value_total += next_value
    if next_value > maximum:
        maximum = next_value

total = next_value_total + first_value
print("The total is {:.1f}".format(total))
print("The maximum is {:.1f}".format(maximum))
```

You can also replace `if next_value > maximum: maximum = next_value` with just `maximum = max(maximum, next_value)`.

Comment: Thank you we haven't learned lists yet in the course, appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you used a list instead you could use [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) and [`max()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) respectively:

```
num_values = int(input("Enter the number of values to process: "))

values = []
for i in range(1, num_values + 1):
  value = float(input("Please enter value %d: " % i))
  values.append(value)

print("The total is {:.1f}".format(sum(values)))
print("The maximum is {:.1f}".format(max(values)))
```

**Example Usage:**

```
Enter the number of values to process:  3
Please enter value 1:  4.0
Please enter value 2:  5.6
Please enter value 3:  7.2324234
The total is 16.8
The maximum is 7.2
```

Try it [here!](https://repl.it/Fe1n/0)

Comment: Thank you we haven't learned lists yet in the course, appreciate your help!